# .net Message Queuing solutions that are not MSMQ

Tags: .net, message-queue

Can anyone recommend a message queuing solution for use with a .net winforms application, preferably open source.

Up until now we have always used MSMQ and found it has worked well for us but the environments the application will be deployed to are not under our control on this project so we cannot guarantee MSMQ will be installed, the people using the application will not have the knowledge to install it and we don't have the resources to talk them all through the process.

So I am looking for something that is kind of like MSMQ but can be included within the application installation package.

Comment: [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579/queue-alternatives-to-msmq-on-windows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) would be my first choice.

Comment: +1 for Rabbit, although you'll need to have the Erlang runtime installed on your environment IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [DotNetMQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetmq/) (and associated [CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193611/DotNetMQ-A-Complete-Message-Queue-System-for-NET)).

Answer (score 1):

WebSphere MQ is fast and stable:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247012.pdf

Comment: WebSphere MQ works, however keep in mind that their .NET client library is outdated and their latest version requires installation on the machine using it.